# Reading Outbound messages from HTTP Streaming Connection in JAVA

Tags: java, http, stream

I am implementing an integration client which will be connected to an **API Gateway** and send requests to the gateway. In short, I am the consumer of the API.

Now, the architecture the opposite party has built that I have to open a http streaming connection and read the outbound messages sent by the system.

In case of http streaming connection, it will be automatically closed if kept on idle state for a while so we have to send continuous heart-beat request to the system so that the stream connection shall stay alive.

Now I have following queries:

1. Do I have to use `URLConnection.openConnection` to open streaming channel?
2. How can I keep the stream open by sending requests? Do I have to open a separate thread for achieving this?
3. What are Outbound messages? Is the term refers to the responses I receive from the API?
4. How can I test it before getting actual testing setup? is there any dummy test case available on the internet where I can open stream and read data? if yes, please suggest any link?

**I have to read JSON Data.**

**I have been provided with following Example Code for HTTP Streaming**

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.lang.invoke.MethodHandles;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLConnection;
import java.net.URLDecoder;

import javax.ws.rs.core.HttpHeaders;

import org.apache.commons.lang.StringUtils;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;

import com.google.gson.Gson;

/** * Sample on Java * Open stream and start StreamReader to read stream in separate thread */

/** * Sample of stream processing */

public class StreamReader implements Runnable {

    private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(MethodHandles.lookup().lookupClass());
    final private BufferedReader in;
    final private boolean toConsole;
    final private String serviceName;

    private final Crypto crypto;

    StreamReader(BufferedReader in, boolean toConsole, String serviceName, Crypto crypto) {
        this.in = in;
        this.toConsole = toConsole;
        this.serviceName = serviceName;
        this.crypto = crypto;
    }

    @Override 
    public void run() { 
        String inputLine; 
        try { 
            stop: 
                while (!Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()) { 
                    try { 
                        while (!StringUtils.isEmpty(inputLine = in.readLine())) { 
                            
                            if ( inputLine.startsWith( serviceName + ":" ) ) { 
                                log.info("Stream message (outgoing from IPS):"); 
                            
                                if (toConsole) 
                                System.out.println("Stream message (outgoing from IPS):"); 
                            
                                String[] s = inputLine.split(":"); 
                            
                            if (s.length >= 2) { 
                                log.debug("Encoded:"); 
                                log.debug(inputLine); 
                                log.trace("Decoded:");
                                String decoded = URLDecoder.decode(s[1], "UTF-8"); 
                                log.trace(decoded); 
                                
                                NReply n = Gson.fromJson(decoded, NReply.class); 
                                log.info("Readable:"); 
                                log.info(n.o.toString()); 
                                
                                if (toConsole) { 
                                    System.out.println("Readable:"); 
                                    System.out.println(n.o.toString()); 
                                } 
                                
                                if (s.length > 2) { 
                                
                                    int lastSemicolon = inputLine.lastIndexOf(':'); 
                                    log.debug("Signed data:"); 
                                    final String signedData = inputLine.substring(0, lastSemicolon); 
                                    log.debug(signedData); 
                                    log.debug("base64 encoded signature:"); 
                                    log.debug(s[2]); 
                                    
                                    try { 
                                        //crypto.checkSignSep(signedData, s[2]); 
                                    } 
                                    catch (Exception e) { 
                                        log.error(e.getMessage(), e); 
                                        } 
                                    }       
                                } 
                            else { 
                                    log.error("Invalid stream message:"); 
                                    log.error(inputLine);
                                    if (toConsole) { 
                                        System.out.println("Invalid stream message:"); 
                                        System.out.println(inputLine); 
                                    } 
                                } 
                        } 
                            else { 
                                log.debug("View's info:"); 
                                log.debug(inputLine); 
                            }
                            if ("CLOSED".equals(inputLine)) { 
                                Thread.currentThread().interrupt(); 
                                break stop; 
                                } 
                            } 
                            Thread.sleep(1000L); 
                            }
                        
                        catch (InterruptedException e) { 
                            log.error(e.getMessage(), e); 
                            Thread.currentThread().interrupt(); 
                            break; 
                        } 
                        catch (Exception e) { 
                            log.error(e.getMessage(), e); 
                            break; 
                        } 
                    } 
                    log.info("polling has been stopped"); 
                    } 
        finally { 
            try {
                in.close(); 
            } 
            catch (IOException e) { 
                log.error(e.getMessage(), e); 
                } 
            } 
        } 
    
    public void openStream(boolean toConsole) throws IOException
    {
        //final URL stream = new URL (hostName+"/stream"); 
        final URL stream = new URL ("url");
        final URLConnection uc = stream.openConnection();
        //uc.setRequestProperty(HttpHeaders.COOKIE, "JSESSIONID=" + heartBeat.getSessionId() );
        uc.setRequestProperty(HttpHeaders.COOKIE, "JSESSIONID=" + "SessionIDFROMSERVICE" );
        final BufferedReader in =new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(uc.getInputStream()));
        StreamReader reader=new StreamReader(in,toConsole,serviceName,crypto);
        Thread thread=new Thread(reader);
        thread.setDaemon(true);
        thread.start();
    }

}
```

Any sort of help is appreciated.. :).

Comment: Do you have any code piece you can post to help us understand deeper?

Comment: Yes I am updating question. Please check.